# Regex for multiple matches .net c#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm workin on a regex:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=[keyb])(.*?)(?=[\/keyb])");
```

With this regex im gettig everything between tags [keyb] and [/keyb]

> example: [keyb]hello budy[/keyb]
>
> output: hello buddy

What about if I want to get everything between [keyb][/keyb] and also [keyb2][/keyb2] ?

> example: [keyb]hello budy[/keyb] [keyb2]bye buddy[/keyb2]
>
> output: hello buddy
>
> bye buddy

Comment: Your example doesn't match your RegEx. Are you parsing some specialized tags denoted by square brackets, or an XML-style document?

Comment: I just edited it! now it matches!

Comment: Hint: use capturing group and backreference.

Comment: Happy [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68059811/11329890) worked for you. Please also kindly upvote my answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```cs
\[(keyb|keyb2)]([\w\W]*?)\[/\1]
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/bXjC9n/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```cs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    keyb                     'keyb'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    keyb2                    'keyb2'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ]                        ']'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w\W]*?                 any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _), non-word characters (all
                             but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \1                       what was matched by capture \1
--------------------------------------------------------
```

**[C# code](https://tio.run/##XVDLTsMwELznK6ycElRcyJGqAglVXIiQANFDkoOTbFsLx7b8gESl3x7spG0Kc9i1Z3f2VenrSijoe6sp36K3ThtoFsHlD79Da/ArbC0jatVKBVpTwfUiCKQtGa1QxYjWaNWSRjII9gFyOIa0Ica5L0FrlBLKo3iIjjke2ijfShJjQHG0RA9hnkWf0JU/3iRxEWX5d74uru7jPJvnt0W4@C@mXFozSFHmRcUOGBOotHWXzQdi5JOi7MDTJz65LOY2hPZFGr8bEke//EPj1DJDGeUwyc6PjbsjqXYoSolxrnFjjWI8EKCjYc7ZadfZqUkcn2tMd/F4dEHBAK8VNfDsukbhWHsjLK/v0P7mEM5Qg5@UsFJnSYE/CLMQT8MdgtEe@v4X)**:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"\[(keyb|keyb2)]([\w\W]*?)\[/\1]";
        string input = @" [keyb]hello budy[/keyb] [keyb2]bye buddy[/keyb2]";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Match found: {0}", m.Groups[2].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

**Results**:

```
Match found: hello budy
Match found: bye buddy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pattern=@"\[keyb.*?](.+?)\[\/keyb.*?\]";
```